# Combinatorics of groupings

Tags: combinatorics

Middle schoolers line up before school.  There are $N$ students in each of 6th, 7th and 8th grades.  So there are $\left(\begin{array}{c}3N\\ N\,N\,N\end{array}\right)$ possible line-ups.

The younger kids are supposed to be first, so e.g. if $N=2$ then the lineup $887766$ is the best, whereas $667788$ is the worst.

We’ll score a line-up as follows.  The worst line-up (as above) gets score 0.  To evaluate a line-up we swap kids until we arrive at the worst line-up, keeping track of a tally as follows:  add 1 point when a 7 passes right of a 6, an 8 passes right of a 7, or a 6 passes right of an 8; subtract 1 for the other swaps betweeen different grades.

*Question:  how many line-ups of a given score are there?*

For example, the line up $887766$ is put into position $667788$ by first moving each of the two $8$’s to the right, each contributing a tally of $2 - 2 = 0,$ thus arriving at $776688$ (with score $0$). Then, we move the two $7$’s to the right, picking up $2\times 2 = 4.$  This (best) score is $4$ when $N=2.$

In general, I think the scores will fall in-between $0$ and $N^2$, and the number with score $k$ will be equal to the number with score $N^2-k$.  But what is that number!?